# MongoDB - Document Failed Validation error when inserting data into a Collection containing enums

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i've programmatically created a collection which contains some fields that have enum values, however, when i try to manually insert some data into the collection on the MongoDB Atlas site, i'll get the document failed validation error.

screenshot of how i am inserting the data using here:
[MongoDB Atlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yByRL.jpg)

also in reference to the screenshot, i tried changing the type to `array` and setting the first element to one of the enumerated types i've said.

**code**

```
await db.createCollection("components", {
      autoIndexId: true,
      validator: {
        bsonType: "object",
        $jsonSchema: {
          required: ["name", "type", "brand", "qty", "price"],
          properties: {
            name: {
              bsonType: "string",
              description: "must be a string and is required",
            },
            type: {
              enum: [
                "Motherboard",
                "Processor",
                "Graphics Card",
                "Memory",
                "Storage",
                "Power Supply",
                "Operating System",
              ],
            },
            manufacturer: {
              enum: ["Nvidia", "AMD", "Intel"],
            },
            brand: {
              enum: [
                "ASUS",
                "Gigabyte",
                "Zotac",
                "MSI",
                "EVGA",
                "Sapphire",
                "Palit",
              ],
            },
            description: {
              bsonType: "string",
            },
            qty: {
              bsonType: "int",
            },
            price: {
              bsonType: "double", // review type
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Comment: What is the data and what is the error?

Comment: the error is "document validation error" which occurs if the data to be inserted fails a validation check.

there's a link in my original post which shows a screenshot of the data i'm trying to insert

Comment: Add the data and the error as text to the post please.